# How to Handle Temporary Exceptions in Asmack

Tags: android, asmack

i built up an application based on aSmack, and obviously every thing about connection is running in a service, so it is very important to keep its connection Alive, as we know services running in background, may get killed upon phone's low sources (usually Ram) , so with the START_STICKY flag on the service, it restarts itself with a null intent.

now i wonder if there be no network on the phone ,or suddenly an unexpected temporary exception happenes in that time, (and because service is restarted reconnectionManager hasnt been set up yet), so the app must get restarted to retrieve its connection. my question is how can i handle these exceptions ? i know i can do some thing like this:

```
 public void connect(){
 try {
                connection.connect();
            } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {

               if(getIntent() == null){
                    connect();
                   return;
                }
              }
 }
```

but this is unprofessional imo, i know there was a way to determine temporary exceptions but unfortunanly i cant either remember or find them. any information is appreciated. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here is what i have done, works perfectly and every thing is counted in that.

this is awhat my service does every time it starts

```
private void connect(){

if (!connection.isConnected()){


            try {
                connection.connect();
            } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {

                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            if(intent ==null){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Could not Connect to The Server , Network Problems , Retrying in 30 Seconds...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Could not Connect to The Server , Network Problems...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }

                    }
                });

                if(intent == null){
  //When intent is null, It Means that service got Destroyed middle of app, which    
 //means user has already connected and Authenticated once, but can not do it again. 
 //so thats the key

            nonMainHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            connect();

                        }
                    },30000);
                }


                 e.printStackTrace();
            }


      }

     try {
          if (connection.isConnected() && !connection.isAuthenticated()) {


            try {
                connection.login(LMApplication.userName,LMApplication.passWord);
            } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {

                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(intent != null){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Could not Login Using this Information..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }

                    }
                });

                e.printStackTrace();

                configEnterButton(-1);

            }


          }


        if(connection.isAuthenticated()){

            configEnterButton(100);


            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        goAhead();




        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "Logged in as" + LMApplication.Raw_CurrentUser);
        //TODO
        // check if need to set presence from shared preferences
        Presence p = new Presence(Presence.Type.available,"", 42, Mode.available);
        try {
            connection.sendPacket(p);
        } catch (NotConnectedException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        }else if(intent == null){

            nonMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(connection.isConnected() && !connection.isAuthenticated()){

                        try {
                            connection.login(LMApplication.userName,LMApplication.passWord);
                        } catch (XMPPException | SmackException
                                | IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    if(connection.isConnected() && connection.isAuthenticated()){

                        notifyReconnect();

                    }else if(connection.isConnected()){

                        nonMainHandler.postDelayed(this,10000);

                    }
          }});

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how can i handle these exceptions ?

By performing a reconnect. Most applications I know do schedule the reconnect after a few seconds.

Comment: thats was a newbie answer tbh

Comment: I don't know what else to answer. Maybe you could reword your question.